# no communication between pub/sub code in android using zeromq

Tags: android, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I tried to implement a simple publisher and subscriber in android using zeromq. When i try to debug it loops in subscriber recv. I dont know where i am going wrong. I think it is not able to get any data from the publisher.

Below is the code :subscriber

```
package com.example.jeromqps;
        import java.util.*;

import org.jeromq.ZMQ;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.os.RemoteException;
public class client implements Runnable {

    Messenger messenger;
    public client()
    {
        System.out.println("client started");
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    { 
        ZMQ.Context context=ZMQ.context(1);     
        System.out.println("collecting data from server");
        ZMQ.Socket subscriber=context.socket(ZMQ.SUB);
        subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:4444");
        String code="10001";
        subscriber.subscribe(code.getBytes());
        int totalvalue=0;
        //store the data in a data structure
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        { 
           byte[] msg = subscriber.recv(0);
            String string=new String(subscriber.recv(0));
            StringTokenizer sscanf=new StringTokenizer(string," ");
            int value=Integer.valueOf(sscanf.nextToken());
            String string= new String(msg);
           System.out.println();
            totalvalue+=value;
        }
        int avg=totalvalue;
        Message msg1=Message.obtain();
        msg1.obj=string;
        try {
             messenger.send(msg1);
             System.out.println("sent to main");
             } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

        subscriber.close();
        context.term();

    }
}
```

The publisher code is below

```
    package com.example.jeromqps;
import java.util.*;
import org.jeromq.*;
public class server implements Runnable{

    public server()
    {
        System.out.println("server started");
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        ZMQ.Context context=ZMQ.context(1);
        ZMQ.Socket publisher=context.socket(ZMQ.PUB);
        publisher.bind("tcp://*:4444");

        Random srandom=new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
         System.out.println("in server");
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
        { //System.out.println("in while")
            int zipcode =1000 +srandom.nextInt(10000);
            int temperature = srandom.nextInt(215) - 80 + 1;
                String update = String.format("%05d %d", zipcode, temperature);
            String update="publisher";
            publisher.send(update.getBytes(),0);
        }
        publisher.close();
        context.term();
    }

}
```

Main is below:

```
      package com.example.jeromqps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Handler;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;






public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Handler.Callback {
    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread(new server()).start();
        new Thread(new client()).start();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message arg0)
    {
        String str = new String((byte[]) arg0.obj);
        System.out.println("****");
        System.out.println(str);
        //new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(str).show();
        System.out.println("****");
        textView.append(str+ "\n");
        return false;
    }

}
```

In program loops at  byte[] msg = subscriber.recv(0); in the subscribers class. Where am i going wrong?Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you've got some errors in the code:

In the publisher, `update` is defined twice

```
  String update = String.format("%05d %d", zipcode, temperature);
  String update= "publisher";
```

You have a similar problem in the subscriber code, `string` is defined twice...

```
String string = new String(subscriber.recv(0));
String string = new String(msg);
```

In the subscriber, you're receiving messages twice in the same iteration..

```
    byte[] msg = subscriber.recv(0);
    String string = new String(subscriber.recv(0));
```

...you only need this in the loop to receive...

```
String string = new String(subscriber.recv(0));
```

Try fixing those problems and see how far you get...

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake while pasting the code here .Some of the  commented code did not get commented here. I made a few changes and it worked. I think it was not working because of the port number.

Comment: @user1715513 Can you please post your working code so that others may benefit? Thank you.

Comment: @Jeremy Not sure what I did with that code; I suggest browsing the Java examples for ZeroMq, great info there, hope it helps!  https://github.com/imatix/zguide/tree/master/examples/Java

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution to the question posted here, but reading this question I noticed that `0` was specified as the second parameter in the `send(...)` method, which subsequently matches the parameter set in the `recv(...)` method.

I have a simple pub/sub system set up and couldn't figure out why messages weren't being sent. I was using `recv(0)` but was specifying some random flag in the `send(...)` method. Changing the value to `0` fixed my issues.

Figured I'd post this here as it was from reading through the code in the question that I happened to have that thought. So maybe this will help someone else in the future.